# How to select multiple data from database and assign it into session?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to select data from database and assign it into session. later i want to call it and used it..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = 
  '$password'";
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die ("Error: " . 
  mysqli_error($mysqli));
  $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if($row == 0)
  {
     echo "Invalid Username/Password. Click here to <a href = 
     'login.html'>Login</a>";
  }
  else
  {
     $sql = "SELECT accname FROM account WHERE email = '$email'";
     $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
     $_SESSION['accname']= array_column($rows, 'accname');
     $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
     $_SESSION['fname'] = $r['fname'];
     $_SESSION['lname'] = $r['lname'];
     $_SESSION['email'] = $r['email'];
     header("Location: dashboard.php");
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If a user can have multiple `accname` values associated with their email address, then you can use `array_column` to extract all those values from your result data:

```
$sql = "SELECT accname FROM account WHERE email = '$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
$_SESSION['accname']= array_column($rows, 'accname');
```

If there can be only one `accname`, you can simply change the call to `mysqli_fetch_all` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
$sql = "SELECT accname FROM account WHERE email = '$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['accname']= $row['accname'];
```

Comment: thanks for respond sir but i have try to echo the session but it not come out. I have try to echo 'email' and its work.

Comment: @FarhanHakim what do you mean by "it not come out"? I presume you have `session_start` at the start of your code? Did you try `print_r($_SESSION);`? you can't use `echo $_SESSION;` because it is an array. Do you have MySQL error checking enabled?

Comment: yes sir, the session not come out. I try to use print_r($_SESSION);and it come out like this ( [accname] => [fname] => zaki [lname] => zakaria [email] => zaki@zakaria.com ). I have session_start.

Comment: @FarhanHakim I had a typo in the second version of my code (in line 4 `$rows` should have been `$row`). Was that the one you were using? I have corrected it in the answer now.

Comment: @FarhanHakim I'm glad it's working - sorry about wasting your time with my typo.